# Is there a way to capture specific GET request from all requests on current page in express.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Im developing simple app that enables you to register new user, log in and display a shopping card after it. Im nearly finishing my project, but I need to do a couple of things.

Until the moment of displaying shopping card, a lot of things is going on. You must register yourself, then log in, then certain animation is being displayed and finally after it the line of code `window.location.href = "shop.html"` is being executed. It may not be the best solution, but as for now I want to keep it that way. Im using template enginge handlebars for my express project, but those handlebars are used only for displaying items in specific place of shopping card,nothing more. I want the rest to be on client side.

After Im on page shop.html, there is a lot of GET requests going on in network card in my browser. There is also get request of this shop.html but how can I capture this request in express ? I will need to do the session later. So finally I want to redirect user that is not signed in to login page, in the case of trying displaying localhost/shop.html instantly without signing in.

Comment: Why not send 401 if the user is not logged in and capture that in your front and then redirect to the login page?

Comment: I will try it but I have not created session yet. I wanted to approach it from the very beginning, but maybe Im wrong with this.